# Help us make Mi Yodeya referencer even better!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, citing-sources, user-scripts, referencer

> **UPDATE** by msh210**:** The contributions below have been collected by HodofHod and are being worked into the script. **Do not add further contributions below. Any further suggestions for modification to the script, including a such as might have been made below, should be made in [the dedicated chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9434).**

Several times, the community has discussed and [requested](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1232) an easier way to link to sources. So recently, with the help of Hashem yisborach[<strike>, and</strike>](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=38b&format=pdf) @Menachem, I threw together a [quick script to do just that.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1738/883) Right now, it supports linking to Tanach and most of Talmud Bavli. Feedback has been very positive, and lots of people have stopped by the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9434/discussion-and-debugging-for-mi-yodeya-referencer) to offer their help with debugging and suggestions. We're really happy with what we've done so far, and we'd like to take this even farther, but we need your help!

The next steps are adding Rambam and Shulchan Aruch. Now, while Shulchan Aruch will be (be"H) simple, Rambam presents a challenge. People often quote Rambam by topic, not book, and there are **86** topics to choose from! (I.e., Avodat Yom haKippurim,  Me`ilah,    Korban Pesach, etc., etc., etc.) Like Tanach and Bavli, we have to be able to recognize many different spellings and abbreviations of these topic names. This is much more difficult, not just because there are more topics, but also because their names are longer and more complex.

So here's where you come in! The easiest, fastest, and best way to do this is, is to crowdsource it! Many hands make light work, and many Jews, from many backgrounds, make many spellings. So I'm putting a Community Wiki answer below for each **book** of Rambam, together with the topics they include.

---

### TL;DR

Please help us add different possible spellings and abbreviations for the topic (*and book*) names of Mishna Torah!

- We're going for broadest match, not most correct. If you think there's sommon mistaken spelling, add it!
- To allow for broadest matching, and least repetition, list spellings for each word in the topic name separately. For example: `Kiddush HaChodesh` - > `kiddush`, `kidush`, `hachodesh`, `chodesh`,
- Abbreviations! `Kiddush Hachodesh` -> `kh`, `khc`, `kd` (Try to avoid abbreviations that might be shared by another topic, but don't worry if they do.)
- English alphabet only! Preferably no punctuation, except for commas separating each spelling.
- Add what *you* would write it as!

Comment: "sommon mistaken spelling" `:-)`

Comment: Please use your upvotes to keep the 14 answers in the correct order, Mada at the top.

Comment: @DoubleAA you can just order by oldest and you'll be fine.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Nope. Mishpatim would be before Avoda, for instance.

Comment: Should this question just be deleted?

Comment: @msh210 Should this post be closed (locked?) as per your update?

Answer (score 4):

## Madda

mada, madda, maddah, maddah, made, madde, madeh, maddeh,
mad, hamada, hammadda, hamadah, hammaddah

**Yesodey haTorah**
yesodei, yesode, yisodei, yisode, yisodey, yesodey,
hatorah, torah, hatora, tora,
yht, yt, yes, yis,

**De'ot**
deot, deos, deyos, deios, deyot, deiot, daot, daos,

**Talmud Torah**
talmud,
torah, tora,
tt, tal,

**Avodah Zarah veChukot haGoyim**
avodat, avodas,
kochavim,
chukot, chukos, vchukot, vchukos, vechukot, vechukos,
goyim, goim, hagoyim, hagoim,
ak,
zara, zarah, 
chuk,
goy,
az,

**Teshuvah**
teshuva, teshuvah, tshuvah, tshuva,
tsh, tesh

Answer (score 2):

## Ahava

**Kri'at Shema**
krias, kriat, kriyat, kriyas,
shema, shma
ks, krs, krsh,

**Tefilah u'Birkat Kohanim**
tefilah, tefila, tfila, tfilah, tefilla, tefillah,
birkat, birkas, birchas, birchat, ubirkat, ubirkas, ubirchas, ubirchat,
kohanim, cohanim, 
tbk,

**Tefillin, u'Mezuzah, v'Sefer Torah**
tefillin, tefilin, tfilin,
mezuzah, mezuza, mzuza, mzuzah, umezuzah, umezuza, umzuza, umzuzah,
sefer, vsefer, usefer,
torah, tora,
stam,

**Tzitzis**
tzitzis, tzizit, tsitsit, tsitsis, sisis, sisit,

**Berachot**
berachot, berachos, brachos, brachot,

**Milah**
milah, mila, bris, brit

**Seder HaTefila**
seder, siddur, sidur,
hatefilah, hatefila, hatfilah, hatfila, tfila, tefila, tfilah, tefilah, tefilla, tefillah,

Comment: `tefillah` can't be both!!!

Comment: @DoubleAA Sure can! We just have to require "seder" for the latter.

Comment: mezuza looks like someone fell asleep in the middle of typing :)

Answer (score 2):

## Zmanim

zemanim, zmanim, zem, zm, zmn, zman,

**Shabbos**
shabbat, shabat, shabbos, shabes, shabbes, shab, sh,

**Eruvin**
eruvin, eiruvin, eruv, er, eru

**Shevitat Asor**
shvisas, shevisas, shevitat, shvitat,
asor,

**Shevitat Yom Tov**
shvisas, shevisas, shevitat, shvitat, 
yomtov, yt, yom, tov

**Chometz U'Matzah**
chametz, hametz, hamets, hamets, chamets, chometz, chometz, cham, ham,
matza, massa, masa, matsa, matzo,
chum, chom, cm,

**Haggadah**

haggada, hagada, haggadah, hagadah

**Shofar, Sukkah, vLulav**
shofar,
sukkah, succah, suka, sukah, sukka, succa,
lulav, vlulav, ululav,

**Shekalim**
sheqalim, shekalim, shkalim, shekolim, shkolim, shek, shkolim,

**Kiddush HaChodesh**
chodesh, hodesh, khodesh,
hachodesh, hahodesh, hakhodesh,
kidush, kiddush, kid,
khc,

**Ta'aniyot**
taaniyos, taanios, taaniyot, taaniot, tanios, taniyos, taanis, taanit, tanis, tan, taan, taniyot,

**Megillah vChanukah**
meg, mg, megila, mgila, megilla, megillah,
chanukah, chanukkah, hanukah, hanukkah, hanuka, hanukka, chanuka, channuka, vchanukah, vchanukkah, vhanukah, vhanukkah, vhanuka, vhanukka, vchanuka, vchannuka,
chan, han,
mgc, mgvch, mgch,

Comment: `shevisas` can't be both!!!

Comment: @DoubleAA Sure can! Just need to make sure it requires another term to match succesfully.

Answer (score 2):

## Nashim

nashim, noshim,

**Ishut**

ishus, eshus,

**Gerushin**

geirushin, gittin, gitin,

**Yibbum vChalitzah**

yibbum, yibum,
chalitza, chalitzah, halitza, halitzah, haliza, chaliza, halizah, chalizah, halissa,

**Naarah Besulah**

naarah, nara, naara, narah,
betulah, besula, bsula, bsulah, besulah

**Sotah**

sota, sotah, soda, :)

Answer (score 2):

## Kedusha

kedusha, kdusha, kdushah

**Issurei Biah**
issurei, isurei, isure, isurey, issurey,
bia, biah, biya, biyah,
ib, isub,

**Ma'achalot Assurot**
maachalot, machalot, maachalos, machalos,
assurot, asurot, assuros, asuros,
ma, macha, maacha,

**Shechitah**
shechitah, shechita, shehita, shehitah,

Answer (score 0):

## Zeraim

zerayim, zraim, zrayim,

**Kilayim**
kilaayim, kilaim,
kil,

**Matnot Aniyim**

matanos, aniyim, tzedaka, mattanot, mattanos, matnot, matnos, aniyiim

**Terumot**
terumos, terumot, terum,
ter,

**Maaserot**
maaserot, maaseros, maaser, mayseros, maser, mayser
maas, mays,

**Maaser Sheini v'Neta Revai**
maaser, maser, mayser
sheni, sheini
neta, vneta,
revai, kerem
msvnr, msnr, ms,

**Bikkurim u'Shar Matnot Kehuna she'b'Gevulin**
bikkurim, bikurim,
shar, shaar, ushar, ushaar, vshar, vshaar,
matnot, matnos, matanos, matanot,
kehuna, kehunah,
shebgevulin, shebgvulin
bik, bikk,

**Shemita v'Yovel**
shmita, shemitta, shemitah, shmitah, shmitta,
yovel, yoivel, yoival
sy, shy,

Answer (score 0):

## Haflaa

hafla, haflu, haflaa,
haf,

**Shevuot**

shvuot, shvuos, shevuos, shv, shevuot,

**Nedarim**

neder, ned, nedarim,

**Nezirut**

nazir, nezirus, nezerut, nezirus, nez, naz, nz,

**Arachin v'Charamim**

arachin, erkin, erchin,
charamot, charamos, haramos, haramim, charamim, herem, cherem, vcharamot, vcharamos, vharamos, vharamim, vcharamim, vherem, vcherem,
ach, arch, arvch,

Answer (score 0):

## Avodah

avoda, avodah

**Beit Habechirah**
beit, beis, bet, bes,
habechira, habechirah, habchira, habchirah, habekhira, habekhirah,
bh,

**Klei Hamikdash v'ha'Ovdim Bo**
klei, kley,
hamikdash, hamikdosh, mikdash, mikdosh,
vhaovdim, ovdim, haovdim,
bo, ba,

**Biat Hamikdash**
biat, bias, mikdash, hamikdash, mikdosh, hamikdosh,

**Issurei Mizbeiach**
issurei, isurei, issurey, isurey, isure, issure,
mizbeiach, mizbeyach, mizbeyakh,

**Temidin uMusafin**
tmidin, temidin, temidim, tmidim, tamidim, tamidin, tamid,
musafin, musafim, umusafin, umusafim,

**Maaseh Hakorbonos**
maseh, maaseh, mayseh, mayse,
hakorbonos, hakorbanot, hakorbanos,

**Pesulei Hamukdashim**
pesulei, psulei, pesuley, psulei,
hamukdashim, mukdashim,

**Avodat Yom haKippurim**
avodat, avodas, avoidas,
yom,
hakippurim, hakipurim, kipurim, kippurim, kippur, kipur,
ayk, yk,

**Me`ilah**
meilah, meila,

Answer (score 0):

## Shofetim

shoftim, shofetim

**Sanhedrin v'ha'Onshin haMesurin Lahem**

sanhedrin, 
vhaonshin, onshin,
hamesurin, mesurin,
lahem,
sanhed

**Edut**

edus, edut, eduth, edhuth, eidim, eid,

**Mamrim**

mamrim, mamrin,

**Avel**

avel, uvel, aveilus, aveilut, avelut, avelus, aveluth,

**Melachim u'Milchamot**

melachim, melech, mashiach, melochim, mlochim, mlachim,

milchamos, milchamot, milchomos, milchamteihem, milchamosehem, milchamoseihem, milchamotehem, milchamoteihem, milchomosehem, milchomoseihem, milhamotehem, milhamoteihem, vmilchamos, vmilchamot, vmilchomos, vmilchamteihem, vmilchamosehem, vmilchamoseihem, vmilchamotehem, vmilchamoteihem, vmilchomosehem, vmilchomoseihem, vmilhamotehem, vmilhamoteihem,

Answer (score 0):

## Korbanot

korbanot, korbonos, korbanos, karbanot,

**Korban Pesach**
korban, karban,
pesah, pesach, pesakh,

**Chagigah**
chagiga, chagigah, hagiga, hagigah,

**Bechorot**
bechorot, bechoros, bchorot, bchoros,

**Shegagot**
shegagot, shegagos, shgagot,shgagos,

**Mechusarei Kapparah**
mechussarey, mechusarei, mechussarei,
kapparah, kappara, kaparah, kapara,
mk, mech,

**Temurah**
temurah, temura, tmurah, tmura,

Answer (score 0):

## Taharah

t, ta, tah, tahara, taharah, tahorah, tahora, tahra, tahrah

**Tum'at Met**
tumas, tumat, 
met, mes, meit, meis, mais, mait,

**Parah Adummah**
para, parah, poro, poroh,
aduma, adumah, adummah, adumma,

**Tum'at Tsara`at**
tumas, tumat,
tzaraas, tzoras, tzaras, tzarat, tsarat, tsaraat,

**Metamm'ey Mishkav uMoshav**
metammey, metammei, metamei, metamey, mtamei, mtamey
mishkav, mishkov,
moshav,
mmm,

**She'ar Avot haTum'ah**
shear, shar, shaar,
avot, avos,
hatumah, hatuma, hatumaa, tumaa, tumah,
sat,

**Tum'at Okhalin**
tumas, tumat,
okhalin, ochalin, oichlin, oichlim,
to,

**Kelim**
keilim, kelim,
kei, ke,

**Mikvot**
mikvaot, mikvot, mikvos, mikvaos, mikvah
mik, mkv,

Answer (score -1):

## Mishpatim

mishpatim, mishpotim,

**Sechirut**

sechirus, sachir, schirus, schirut,

**Sheailah u'Pikadon**

sheeilah, shailah, shaylah, shayla, sheaila,
pikadon, piqadon, upikadon, upiqadon,

**Malve v'Loveh**
malve, malveh, 
loveh, love, vloveh, vlove,

**Toen v'Nitan**
toen, toain,
nitan, nitaan, vnitan, vnitaan,

**Nachalot**
nachalos, nachlos, nachlot, nahalot, nahlot, nachalaos,

Answer (score -1):

## Nezikim

**Nizkei Mammon**
nizkei, nizkey, niskei, niskey, nizke
mamon, mammon, mamoin, mumoin,
nm, niz,

**Genevah**
genevah, geneivah, geneva, geneiva, gneiva, gneva, gneivah, gnevah,
gen, gne,

**Gezelah va'Avedah**
gezelah, gezeilah, gzeilah, gzelah, gzela, gezela, gezeila, gzeila,
avedah, aveda, aveidah, aveida, vaavedah, vaaveda, vaaveidah, vaaveida, vavedah, vaveda, vaveidah, vaveida,
ga, gva,

**Chovel uMazzik**
chovel, choivel, choyvel,
mazzik, mazik, umazzik, umazik,
cm, chov,

**Rotzeach uShmirat Nefesh**
rotseach, rotzeach, rotseah, rotzeah, rotzeiach,
shmirat, shmiras, ushmirat, ushmiras, shemirat, shemiras, ushemirat, ushemiras, 
nefesh, nafesh,
rsn, rot, rotz, rusn, rsn,

Answer (score -1):

## Kinyan

kinyan, kinian,

**Mechirah**
mechira, mechirah, mehira, mehirah, mchira, mchirah, mekhira, mekhirah
mech, mch,

**Zechiyah uMattanah**
zechiyah, zechiyah, zekhiya, zekhiyah, zechia, zechiah,
mattana, mattanah, matana, matanah, umattana, umattanah, umatana, matanah,
zech, zch, zm

**Shechenim**
shechenim, shekhenim, shehenim,

**Sheluchin veShuttafin**
sheluchin, shluchin, sheluchim, shelukhin, shluchim,
shuttafin, shutafin, shutfin, vshuttafin, vshutafin, vshutfin, veshuttafin, veshutafin, veshutfin,
ss, svs

**Avadim**
avadim, avodim,
av, avd,