# Mi Yodeya Referencer: A Syntax for Linking to Sources

Tags: discussion, citing-sources, hyperlinks, user-scripts, referencer

Several times, the community has discussed and [requested](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1232) an easier way to link to sources. So recently, with the help of Hashem yisborach[<strike>, and</strike>](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=38b&format=pdf) @Menachem, I threw together a [quick script to do just that.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1738/883)

It links to Tanach and most of Talmud Bavli, and with the [help of the community](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/help-us-make-mi-yodeya-referencer-even-better), we've added Rambam's Mishna Torah, and subsequently Shulchan Aruch and Kitzur Shulchan Aruch.  Though it has lots of features, the markdown-like syntax is simple, and it accepts many spellings and abbreviations. It also accepts "flags", extra options that that can be added at the end of the reference.

- Tanach:

  - `[t bereishis 3 4]` -> http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8167#v=4
  - `[t bereishis 3 4 l]` -> [Bereishit 3:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8167#v=4)
  - Add an `r` to link to rashi, an `m` for Mechon Mamre, or an `s` for Sefaria.
  - The verse is optional, omit it to link the whole chapter.
- Gemara:

  - `[g berachot 4b]` -> http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=4b&format=pdf
  - Add an `l` like above, or a `t` to link to the text version.
- Mishna Torah

  - `[mt deos 4 2]` -> http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1204.htm#2
  - Add an `l`, like above, or an `e` to go to Chabad.org's English version.
  - Both the chapter and the halacha can be omitted.
- Shulchan Aruch

  - `[sa oc 12]` -> http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x363
  - Sections names are `oc` (Orach Chaim), `yd` (Yoreh Deah), `eh` (Even HaEzer), or `cm` (Choshen Mishpat).
- Kitzur Shulchan Aruch

  - `[ksa 12 3]` -> http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur12.html#3

  The script automagically detects thousands of spellings, and will convert them to one main   spelling. If you want to keep your own spelling simply use a `u` instead of the `l`.

More syntax rules [available here](https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/blob/master/README.md), and in Menachem's excellent write-up below.

---

- **Want to download it?** [Click here for instructions](https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/blob/master/Installing.md)
- **Want to see the code?** [Click here](https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/blob/master/MY.Referencer.user.js)
- **Found a bug? Add a spelling or abbreviation? Request a feature?** Ping @HodofHod in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9434/discussion-and-debugging-for-mi-yodeya-referencer)
- **Just want to say thanks?** A lot of people contributed to make this happen. @Menachem, @msh210, @CharlesKoppelman, @IsaacMoses, @MonicaCellio, @DoubleAA, are just the ones at the tip of my tongue.

---

### If people find this useful and convenient, I will continue developing it, adding more features and sources, so please let me know!

---

<sup><sup>Also, the formatting on this question is driving me meshugeh. If anyone can figure out a cleaner more accessible form, *please* edit it!</sup></sup>

Comment: Splendid! Thank you very much for writing this user script. Could someone please add support for linking to Yona Newman's [bilingual Kitzur Shulchan Aruch](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kiz-index.html), to Chabad's [almost-complete Mishneh Torah in English](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682956/jewish/Mishneh-Torah.htm), and to the Dafyomi Advancement Forum's English-language [point-by-point outlines of all of Shas](http://dafyomi.co.il/sanhedrin/points/sn-ps-011.htm)?

Comment: @unforgettableid, look down. Already got two out of three. :)

Comment: Ah. I was only looking at the question — not the answer. :)

Comment: Could you please tag the question as [wiki], so that we can edit it?

Comment: The automagical transliteration feature is impressive. You might be able to simplify the user script by replacing the comma-separated lists of possible transliterations with regular expressions.

Comment: Hmmm. It looks like GitHub hosts a [bug tracker](https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/issues) for the user script. Intriguing.

Comment: If you crossed out "and" in the first paragraph because of where it says on Sotah 38b "דאמר רבי יהושע בן לוי אפילו מחיצה של ברזל אינה מפסקת בין ישראל לאביהם שבשמים", that actually indicates that the "and" poses no problem; if an iron partition can't separate between a Jew and our Father in Heaven, a three-letter conjunction certainly can't. :)

Answer (score 13):

Valid for version: 4.1.0

**HELP:** Typing `[h]` or `[help]` will display this documentation.

**SYNTAX:**

[{SCOPE} ({BOOK}|{SECTION}) ({CHAPTER} ({VERSE}|{HALACHA})|{PAGE}) {FLAGS}]

**SCOPE:** What are you trying to link to, possible options include

- `t` -- Tanach

  - [{SCOPE} {BOOK} {CHAPTER} {VERSE} {FLAGS}]
  - {VERSE} {FLAGS} are optional
  - Available Flags: `l` `u` `r` `m` `s`
- `g`  -- Gemara (Talmud Bavli)

  - [{SCOPE} {BOOK} {PAGE} {FLAGS}]
  - {FLAGS} is optional
  - Available Flags: `l` `u` `t`
- `mt` -- Mishna Torah (Rambam)

  - [{SCOPE} {SECTION} {CHAPTER} {HALACHA} {FLAGS}]
  - {CHAPTER} {HALACHA} {FLAGS} are optional
  - Available Flags: `l` `u` `e` `h`
- `ksa` -- Kitzur Shulchan Aruch

  - [{SCOPE} {CHAPTER} {HALACHA} {FLAGS}]
  - {HALACHA} {FLAGS} are optional
  - Available Flags: `l` `u`
- `sa` -- Shulchan Aruch

  - [{SCOPE} {SECTION} {CHAPTER} {HALACHA} {FLAGS}]
  - {HALACHA} {FLAGS} are optional
  - Available flags `l` `u`
  - Note: The syntax accepts a se'if/halacha number, but Hebrewbooks does not support linking directly to these, so the link will go to the beginning of the siman/chapter.

**BOOK|SECTION:** Which Book|Section in the **SCOPE** are you trying to link to?

- A wide variety of spellings for the different books in the different scopes are supported

**CHAPTER:** Which Chapter in the **BOOK|SECTION** are you trying to link to?

- Only valid chapters for the BOOK|SECTION are supported.
- Mandatory for Tanach, KS"A, and Shulchan Aruch.
- Optional for Mishna Torah.

**VERSE:** Which verse in the **CHAPTER** do you want to link to

- For Tanach SCOPE
- Optional

**HALACHA:** Which Halacaha in the **CHAPTER** or **SECTION** do you want to link to

- Optional for Mishna Torah SCOPE
- Optional for KS"A SCOPE
- Optional for Shulchan Aruch SCOPE

**PAGE:** Which page in the **BOOK** of the Gemara do you want to link to

- For Gemara SCOPE
- Mandatory
- Must be in ?A or ?B format, e.g. 3A or 3B (or 3a, 3b, it is not case sensitive)

**FLAGS:** Flags can be used together with other Flags

- Universal

  - `l` --  Instead of generating a link, create hyperlinked text
  - `u` -- When creating hyperlink text, instead of using default spelling, use actual spelling entered

    - affects **BOOK|SECTION**
- Tanach

  - `r` -- show Rashi on chapter on Chabad.org

    - ignored when using Mechon Mamre or Sefaria link
  - `m` -- use Mechon Mamre link instead of Chabad.org
  - `s` -- use Sefaria.org link instead of Chabad.org
- Gemara

  - `t` -- link to Hebrewbooks.org's text of the Daf, instead of PDF scan.
- Mishna Torah

  - `e` -- link to English translation of Rambam on Chabad.org
  - `h` -- link to HebrewBooks.org version of Rambam

Comment: Thank you for this detailed post! Could you please tag it as [wiki], so that we can edit it?