# What user scripts do we recommend for use on Mi Yodeya?

Tags: discussion, faq, user-scripts

A [user script](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/user-script) is a usually-small device that you can add to your web browser to change how specific websites or all websites appear to you. It can be a way, for example, to add functionality to a site such as Mi Yodeya for yourself that doesn't exist for people who don't have the script installed.

**What user scripts do we recommend to enhance the experience of using Mi Yodeya?**

I suggest one answer per script or functionally-closely-related group of scripts, perhaps plus a Community Wiki catalog with links to the answers.

Answer (score 10):

**Script:** Mi Yodeya Referencer  by @[HodofHod](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/883/hodofhod) (Me!).

**Description:** Instant linking to Tanach, Gemara, and Mishna Torah. Just add brackets! (And a prefix).

**Main Post:** [Mi Yodeya Referencer: A Syntax for Linking to Sources](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/mi-yodeya-referencer-a-syntax-for-linking-to-sources)

**Instructions/Link:** https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/blob/master/Installing.md

Answer (score 6):

**Deprecated:** This functionality is now built into the site, and SE used HodofHod's script as a starting point.

---

**Script:** Hebrew keyboard, by @[HodofHod](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/883/hodofhod).

**Description:** on-demand virtual keyboard for posts and chat (and with nikudot, even!)

**Main post:** https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1781/472

**Instructions/Link:** https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/blob/master/Installing.md