# Reference to good texts

Tags: discussion, citing-sources, hyperlinks, quotations

Following this: [Is there some way to make it easier to quote and find relevant texts?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/is-there-some-way-to-make-it-easier-to-quote-and-find-relevant-texts)

[Hebrewbooks](http://hebrewbooks.org) is a great site, very helpful with sources and texts, a wonderful interface and good options. Still, sometimes looking up a book can be frustrating and annoying.

Is it possible to have a reference to good texts, and/or good versions of books (e.g. SA with *nosei kelim* etc.) to use when quoting?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1232

Comment: By the way, [WikiShivah](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99) has a sort of agreement with Responsa.co.il that automatically has a "מקור" feature: You put the book name in, and choose chapter and verse (or whatever), and it gives you a free link ([this page](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%96%D7%95%D7%92%D7%95%D7%AA) quotes one such link)

Comment: @ba, that's what I was referencing [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/147/is-there-some-way-to-make-it-easier-to-quote-and-find-relevant-texts#comment3904_150) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dr. Melech Tanen's ["Sources on the Net"](http://www.jewishsources.org) is such a reference.

Comment: Very good! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This might also be useful for earlier works: http://rabbinics.org/

Answer (score 3):

[`WikiText` (`וויקיטקסט`)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99) is also really great!!

[http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/עמוד_ראשי](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99)

(Thanks to @Moses [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23384/1863))

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to make a wiki to combine answers and add, perhaps by category:

- [Mechon Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org) -  Tanach, Talmud, some Rishonim
- [Vikitekst (Wikitext)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99) -  Lots of different sefarim, Talmud with Rashi and Tosefos
- [Toras Emes (Ateres)](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/a_root.html) -  Tanach, Talmud, Rambam, Halacha, Mussar, lots of stuff.
- [Sources on the Net](https://docs.google.com/document/edit?id=1ZfHfZsLh2qYBM6Q6Qp18csQvYQMBUOvjfwPCRn9iyJk&pli=1) -  Tanach, Talmud, Rambam, Halacha, lots of other categories.